# Delete entire word with deleteBackward in custom keyboard on iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, keyboard, ios8

i'm starting to develop a custom keyboard with iOS8 and objective-c. I'd like to create a delete button that deletes a single character, at insertion point, when single-pressed, and deletes entire words when it's hold pressed. the deleteBackward seems to delete a single character, but on Apple developers docs i've found:

> To let you determine how much text is appropriate to delete when you call the deleteBackward method, obtain the textual context near the insertion point from the documentContextBeforeInput property of the textDocumentProxy property, as follows:

```
NSString *precedingContext = self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput;
```

> You can then delete what you determine to be appropriate—for example,
>   a single character, or everything back to a whitespace character.

But i don't understand how to achieve that... Is there a way to delete a complete word?

EDIT: I've found the solution... it's a simple tokenize on documentContextBeforeInput:

```
-(void)pressDeleteKey{
NSArray *tokens = [self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
for (int i = 0; i < [[tokens lastObject] length];i++) {
    [self.textDocumentProxy deleteBackward];
}
```

}

Comment: I made the solution work in my case by adding [self.textDocumentProxy deleteBackward]; after the for loop. This deletes the space inside the array.

Answer (score 5):

Swift 1.2 Solution:

```
extension String {

    var length : Int {
        get{
            return count(self)
        }
    }  
}


func deleteLastWord() {

        if let textArray:[String]? = proxy.documentContextBeforeInput?.componentsSeparatedByString(" "){
        if let validArray = textArray{
            for var i=0; i<validArray.last!.length; i++ {
                            proxy.deleteBackward()
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best and *only* bet is to go char by char until your "word" has been removed.

Instead of relying on "spaces" I would try enumerating the string in substrings like such:

```
[string enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, string.length) options:NSStringEnumerationByWords | NSStringEnumerationLocalized usingBlock:^(NSString * _Nullable substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    // Do whatever you want with the words (substrings)
    [words addObject:@[substring, [NSValue valueWithRange:substringRange]]];
}];
```

Then just delete backwards for the respective number of characters from the range you found.

From Apple's *official* documentation:

> When using `UITextDocumentProxy`, you will have **no easy way** to remove text for a range, substring, or anything else that might make your life more convenient. Just write your own methods! Happy coding!

.. lol

Comment: Please provide the link to the official Apple documentation where you found that quote.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for answer for this question too.
Till now, i have to use for loop to delete backward letter by letter.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no simple `replaceStringForRange` or `replaceOccurrence...` method for proxies. *Unless* you loop through each character until your word is gone.